# Can anyone tell me why this list disappears when I change the padding but not the other?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I change the padding of my ul.navButtons and set the padding to 0 it works, however, the list .navSpacers doesn't move with it (obviously).

So what I'm trying to do is I want to set the ul.navSpacers to padding 0 but it disappears. How do I prevent this from happening? I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4catmwo3/)

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

li {
  background: rgba(232, 232, 232, 1);
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  font-size: 100%;
}

li.p1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 140px 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}

li.p2 {
  margin-top: 65px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 140px 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}

li.p3 {
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 140px 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 166%;
}

.spacer1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 130%;
  background: black;
  padding: 13% 200% 43% 24%;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  cursor: default;
}

.spacer2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 293%;
  background: black;
  padding: 13% 200% 43% 24%;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="navTable">
        <ul class="navButtons">
            <li class="p1">List</li>
            <li class="p2">List</li>
            <li class="p3">List</li>
        </ul> 
        <ul class="navSpacers">
            <li class="spacer1"></li>
            <li class="spacer2"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: why you need this padding? add px after 0 maybe will solve this...

Comment: I've tried both ways, adding px also makes it disappear.

Comment: Both lists use `position: absolute;` so they overlap.

Comment: Why not have the spaces in the same list as the items so not to require position absolute?

Comment: maybe overlap but he should see theme, unless background defined

Comment: looks ok, https://jsfiddle.net/nLa9rz3y/,

Comment: You might want to include your full css in your question as it has a bearing on the rendering results.

Comment: Maybe something like https://jsfiddle.net/4catmwo3/1/ instead of that absolute method?

Comment: There, I included the full CSS in the text and not just in the JSFiddle. Also, this is what it should look like. https://jsfiddle.net/qf5567tL/1/ BUT, the spacers that I have are missing on top and they're not behind it either, I've checked. If you removed the padding:0; from ul then they reappear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qf5567tL/3/ corrected a typo in my class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your nav spacers have no content and no specified size, so the only reason they show up at all is the browser default 40px padding-left for ul items.

You should reconsider how you're making those navigation items, shouldn't rely on position:absolute when it's not really needed.

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

li {
  background: rgb(232, 232, 232);
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 166%;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navTable">
        <ul class="navButtons">
            <li class="p1">List</li>
            <li class="p2">List</li>
            <li class="p3">List</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. However, Is there any chance to make the black spacers shorter? I was trying to create a piano effect. Pretty much self-teaching myself this stuff and could use help on that part. 

Actually. I took what you said and applied text inside the list like a bunch of ||| and it's working perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the black stripes disappear is that the list items in your second unordered list are absolutely positioned and use relative units for their padding. So, they reference the zero padding from their parent element's style, and any percentage of that is also zero. Because the list items have no other content to take up space, the display dimensions end up being 0 x 0.

It looks like another answer has provided an acceptable alternative.